# IAR Embedded IDE - Change board support

Tags: c, embedded, iar

I want to change the board support to my own board but not sure about how to do it.
I took a nRF51_SDK_9 example, for instace IAR Embedded/nRF51_SDK_9/examples/ble_peripheral/ble_app_beacon/

[image]

Comment: What board? What is the core? More details?

Comment: ok, thanks. You can convert to answer @LPs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you circled is a location where you can input defines that are you at compile time. If you inserted in your code a define like `MY_BOARD` that makes your project be compiled for your board, you can simply define it there.